# Parquet. Compressing column with large plain text values

Tags: parquet

I have a table in parquet, where, amongst other columns there is a column that contains large plain text values.

For example, there is a column that contains uncompressed html webpage content. Values in this column differ very slightly one from each other. We may estimate that only 0.5% of content is different between 2 cells. Average uncompressed content size is about 1MB for each cell.

The compressibility of this data is very high. If I save all these values in the file, and use standard compression engine, I can easily achieve 10x-15x compression factor.

But in parquet table compression that is achieved is only 3x. And when I add new rows with exactly the same values, the column size increases linearly. It behaves as content is compressed withing cell only, not between cells.

Is there any way to improve compression factor in this case? I mean to make parquet to compress multiple cells together.

The question is for people who have a deep understanding of parquet internals. I would appreciate any insight, and any ideas where to look at.

Environment: Spark 3.5.0 + Hadoop 3.3.1 + delta lake 3.0.0

I've already tried to enable encoding for v2 (delta encodings), and it didn't give too much improvement. I think the encoding itself as it reduces size for small sized cells, reduces possibility to compress text for larger values.

Current idea that I am considering - is there a possibility to enforce encoding for the column (PLAIN), and not let system to choose?